# send function parameter values into html template using node js

Tags: html, node.js, nodemailer

I'm writing a service in node.js. In that, I used to send the mail to user with the verification link. 
For that I used nodemailer, all works perfectly. In that, I directly used the html part, So I access the token variable. Now I need to move that html part into separate folder. Now the issue is accessing the token(ie, the params value) My code is like, modules/users.js

```
let sendNotification = await mailer.sendMail(userDetail.email, token);
```

When I create user, the token is sent to the userDetail.email. My previous mailer looks like, mailer/applicationMailer.js

```
async function sendMail(userMail, token) {
// let htmlTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/mail.html');
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        pass: '********'
    }
}));

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    to: userMail,
    cc: '',
    subject: 'Account verification',
    // html: htmlTemplate
    html: `<p>To verify your account click <a href="https://employee-attendance-service.herokuapp.com/users/verify?token=${token}">LINK</a></p>` +
            `<p>This link will be expired in two days.</p>` + 
            `<p><strong>Note:</strong> Contact your ADMIN, if the link is expired</p>`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, async function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
};
```

I need to move the html part into template/mail.html and access the htmlTemplate variable. There I cant access the token. I need to pass the param value to html page. How to do that?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use ejs template engine

Comment: Thanks @Mehari, now I used ```replace```.  Further I check with ejs. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are looking for **[EJS](http://ejs.co)**

```
const ejs = require("ejs");

ejs.renderFile(__dirname + "/test.ejs", { token }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
    const mainOptions = {
             from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
             to: userMail,
             cc: '',
             subject: 'Account verification',    
            html: data
        };


        transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, function (err, info) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
    }

    });
```